# how to set the values for a public static final class instance in java

Tags: java, class, static, final

example

```java
public static final class MyClass{
        private long id_;
        public static final int MEMBER_ID_FIELD_NUMBER = 2;
        private long startDate_;
    ....

    }

//meanwhile in another class
class Abc {
        ...
    public final void aFunc {
        MyClass aaa = ???? // here is what I want to know how to set the class values
    ....
    }

}
```

How can I set the value for `MyClass` in the other class? I tried to do "initialize" like

```
MyClass aaa = {
                id_: 123123132,...
            };
```

it just give me error that id_ `can't resolve symbol.

I come from javascript background, that's why I think like this. Any idea how can I initiate the instance with partial / all custom default values for a `public static final class`? Btw, if the back-story can help get a full picture --- I do this for testing a specific class's method which is including an instance of `MyClass`. This is an attempt to mock the values instead having to recreate a whole ActionBean to just test one method.

Comment: `id_` is private (and has a weird name, imho), you can't access it from another class. It's `MyClass`'s duty to give its clients a way to change `id_`'s value (either via a constructor or a method).

Comment: you need to learn more about java programming language because it's different from javascript. Don't expect javascript language paradigms to apply to java.

Answer (score 1):

If it has default constructor (the one without any argument) you can first create object without providing fields values and the set it with setters (if they exist) like so:

```
public final void aFunc {
        MyClass aaa = new MyClass();
        a.setId_(1);
        ...
}
```

If it doesn't have default constructor you need to provide all parameters during object creation, like so:

```
public final void aFunc {
        MyClass aaa = new MyClass(1,2,3);
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to create an object instance and assign values to fields:

1. Call setter methods:

   ```
   public static final class MyClass {
       private long id_;

       public void setId(long id) {
           this.id_ = id;
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   MyClass aaa = new MyClass();
   aaa.setId(123123132);
   ```
2. Use a constructor with arguments:

   ```
   public static final class MyClass {
       private long id_;

       public MyClass(long id) {
           this.id_ = id;
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   MyClass aaa = new MyClass(123123132);
   ```
3. Use public fields. Although not recommended, this is what JavaScript kind of does:

   ```
   public static final class MyClass {
       public long id_;
   }
   ```

   ```
   MyClass aaa = new MyClass();
   aaa.id_ = 123123132;
   ```
4. Use a builder:

   ```
   public static final class MyClass {
       private long id_;

       private MyClass(long id) {
           this.id_ = id;
       }

       public static class Builder {
           private long id_;

           public void id(long id) {
               this.id_ = id;
           }

           public MyClass build() {
               MyClass x = new MyClass();
               x.id_ = this.id_;
               return x;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   MyClass aaa = new MyClass.Builder()
           .id(123123132)
           .build();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options in order to fill the fields with values.
One options is using the public constructor passing all the parameters you want to update:

```
public static final class MyClass{
    private long id_;
    public static final int MEMBER_ID_FIELD_NUMBER = 2;
    private long startDate_;

    public MyClass(long id_, long startDate_) {
        this.id_ = id_;
        this.startDate_ = startDate_;
    }
}
```

You can use it as bellow:

```
public final void aFunc {
    MyClass objectA = new MyClass(1L, 23214112213L);
}
```

Second option is using setters: method per field to add value:

```
public static final class MyClass{
    private long id_;
    public static final int MEMBER_ID_FIELD_NUMBER = 2;
    private long startDate_;
    
    public void setID(long id_) {
         this.id_ = id_;
    }

    public void setStartDate(long startDate_) {
         this.startDate_ = startDate_;
    }
        
}
```

You can use them as bellow:

```
public final void aFunc {
    MyClass objectB = new MyClass();
    objectB.setID(1L);
    objectB.setStartDate(23214112213L);
}
```

But you can combine them. You can have the constructor and bellow the setters.

See [java constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) and
see [setters and getters](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/java-getters-and-setters/)

- For you private fields i assume you need getters too.

Those are part of the basic knowledge you should have. In addition keep in mind there are conventions (naming etc)